# Problema de entradas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu programa está funcionando corretamente para um caso de teste mas quando mais que um ocorre o erro mostrado na imagem. O código a seguir:

```
alfabeto = dict()
entradas = input()
i = 0
for i in entradas:

    texto = input().strip()
    texto = texto.lower()
    texto = texto.replace(' ', "")
    ''' Outra forma de ser feito linha acima
    texto = ''.join(texto.plit())
    ''' 

    for letra in texto:
        if letra not in alfabeto:
            alfabeto[letra] = 1
        else:
            alfabeto[letra] = alfabeto[letra] + 1

    maior = 0
    for chave, valor in alfabeto.items():
        if valor > maior:
            maior = valor
    resultado = []
    for chave, valor in alfabeto.items():
        if valor == maior:
            resultado.append(chave)

    print(''.join(sorted(resultado, reverse=False)))
    alfabeto.clear()
```

entrada utilizada:

```
3
Computers account for only 5% of the country's commercial electricity consumption.
Input
frequency letters
```

[image]

Comment: Não cheguei a analisar o código, mas de início já acho que `for i in entradas` deveria ser, na verdade, `for i in range(int(entradas))`

Comment: Fora o que Anderson falou tu pode apagar a variável `i=0` pq ela não é usada em nenhuma parte desse trecho de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com essas mudanças ele roda mais de uma vez, mas o que você está querendo obter com a lógica por que creio que da pra deixar as coisas menores usando as funções chr() e ord(), não sei se é intencional ou não que alem de remover e juntar os espaços se repetir uma letra ele ignora toda a frase  printa a letra repetida, se não for da uma avisada que ajudo a arrumar.

```
alfabeto = dict()
entradas = int(input("digite o numero de entradas"))
for i in range(0,entradas):

    texto = input("digite a frase").strip()
    texto = texto.lower()
    texto = texto.replace(' ', "")

    for letra in texto:
        if letra not in alfabeto:
            alfabeto[letra] = 1
        else:
            alfabeto[letra] = alfabeto[letra] + 1

    maior = 0
    for chave, valor in alfabeto.items():
        if valor > maior:
            maior = valor
    resultado = []
    for chave, valor in alfabeto.items():
        if valor == maior:
            resultado.append(chave)

    print(''.join(sorted(resultado, reverse=False)))
    alfabeto.clear()
```